# A* Pathfinding - I think I have it down in pseudocode, need verification

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, path-finding, a-star

They say that taking what someone said, and repeating it back is the best form of verifying the basics of a concept (comprehension).  So, I've been reading about A* and translated it into pseudocode, and I think I got it.  Can anyone verify and/or give tips on whether or not this implementation would work?

Sorry if this is rushed, I'm on break at work ;)

```
openList.ClearTiles
closeList.clearTiles
path.clearTiles

openList.Add startTile

While openList.Count > 0 and PathFound = false
    activeTile = openList.GetTileWithLowestPathCost
    openList.remove activeTile
    closeList.add activeTile

    if targetTile.equals(activeTile)
       pathFound = true
    else
       for each activeTile.neighbors as nTile
           if nTile not in openList and not in closeList and IsMovable
              nTile.parent = activeTile
              nTile.hueristic = computeHeuristic
              nTile.movementCost = computeMovementCost
              nTile.pathCost = nTile.hueristic + nTile.movementCost

              openList.add nTile
           elseif isMovable = false
              closelist.add nTile
           endif
       next
    endif
endwhile

if pathFound = true        
   while activeTile.parent is not nothing
       path.insertAtZero activeTile
       activeTile = activeTile.parent
   endwhile
endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one major issue with your pseudo code and one minor issue.

The major issue: 

When you find `nTile`, it might be in `closed` or in `open` already, and in your implementation - you ignore it and skip it. However, if it is in closed or open, **you should check maybe the path cost you just found is better** then the path cost which is in `closed` or `open`, and if it is, remove it from `closed`/`open` and re-insert it to `open` with the new path cost.

The minor issue: 

Sometimes there is more then one target node [there is a set of target nodes, you are looking for a path to one of them]. So instead of `if targetTile.equals(activeTile)` you can check `if heuristicValue(activeTile) == 0` [assuming the heuristic function is [admissible]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) or check `if activeTile is in targetStates`.

Comment: Ooh both shoud be an easy fix!  Thank you much, this should be a lot easier to implement now that I got the base idea down pat!